# Stream Requests Uploads getting slow in iOS Background Session from iOS 15.x

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am working on an app which uses iOS NSURLSession background session to upload the data to the S3 server. From iOS `15.x`, We have observed that transfer speed has become too slow (~10 kbps).

Following is the configuration, I am using

1. Create the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` using [backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1407496-backgroundsessionconfigurationwi)
2. Set [HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1407597-httpmaximumconnectionsperhost) to `8`
3. Set [timeoutIntervalForRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1408259-timeoutintervalforrequest) to `60s`
4. Set [timeoutIntervalForResource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1408153-timeoutintervalforresource) to `86400s` (1 Day)
5. Set [discretionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1411552-discretionary) to `false`
6. Set [TLSMinimumSupportedProtocolVersion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/3362533-tlsminimumsupportedprotocolversi) to `tls_protocol_version_TLSv12`
7. Create the `NSURLSession` using [sessionWithConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1411474-sessionwithconfiguration)
8. send request using [uploadTaskWithRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1411550-uploadtaskwithrequest)

When I tested with iPadOs `14.8.1`, there is no degradation in performance, but with iPadOs `15.3.1` and `15.5`, I can see the performance degradation (uploads getting 6x slow).

When I create the session using [ephemeralSessionConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1410529-ephemeralsessionconfiguration) upload is very fast and there is no degradation (working as before).

**For all the tests, I am keeping the app in foreground only**.

I have few queries:

1. Is there any changes in background session configuration for iOS `15.x` and greater ?
2. We are currently using [backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1407496-backgroundsessionconfigurationwi) to create background sessions. Should we consider moving to [background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app?language=objc) introduced in iOS 13 ?
3. Is it upto the OS (in this case `iOS`) to schedule the requests and we (clients) has no or very little control over the transfer speeds ?

**PS:** The degradation is happening with iOS simulators also.
In case of simulators, somehow it is dependent on macOs versions (as seen from my tests).

On macOs `12.4`, in xCode `13.2`, iOS `12.x`, `13.x`, `14.x`, `15.x` simulators are showing the performance degradation.
When the same app is compiled from macOs `11.4`, xCode `12.4`, iOS `12.x`, `13.x`, `14.x` are **not** showing any performance degradation.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having struggled with this problem myself, I wanted to share the solution - for others, and also for future me when I run into this again and inevitably forget: to fix slow download speeds for uploads using a background session configuration, make sure you configure the request's network service type - this setting works for me:

```
var request = URLRequest(...)
// configure request
request.networkServiceType = .responsiveData
```

`.responsiveAV` also worked for me. Do make sure you are only setting this if it is important that uploads happen in a timely manner - if it isn't important just hand it off to the background session with an appropriately configured timeout and let it get on with it.

Note: this will only have an impact if the upload task is started while the app in the foreground. If the upload task begins when the app is already in the background (for example, you need to do some other work first with some extended background execution time and then resume the upload task) then it will ignore this and behave as if you had set it to `.background` which will be as slow as before as requests started in the background are heavily throttled.

Comment: Have you found a way to configure this in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

The simulator likely just passes the requests straight through to NSURLSession on macOS, so it makes sense that the simulator behavior would coincide with the macOS version.

This sounds like a performance regression in macOS 12 and iOS 15.  Please file a bug with Feedback Assistant if you haven't already, and attach a minimum reproducible sample.

Off the top of my head, I can't think of any reason you'd see a measurable performance difference between an ephemeral and background session unless the out-of-process helper is running at too low a priority.

Background tasks and background downloads are somewhat orthogonal.  The former are running in-process in your app, so if your app crashes, they fail.  The latter run in a separate process, so they are independent of whether your app is running.  Background downloads are more appropriate for large downloads, particularly if your app is large-ish, because it means that iOS can evict your app without terminating the download.

The other obvious question is whether you're ever starting a task while in the background (e.g. in response to completion of another task).  The latter are likely to be throttled, particularly if you start a new transfer after a background upload or download finishes.  You can avoid that penalty by combining resources and uploading them in a single blob (e.g. a zip file).  I'm assuming from your question that you are not, but I just wanted to be certain.  :-)

I'm also assuming that this is either over Wi-Fi or is network-agnostic, given that you also see it on macOS.

Finally, I'm assuming that this isn't an HTTP/3 (QUIC) issue.  That is, of course, the biggest change in NSURLSession in iOS 15 and macOS 12, so if I were pointing fingers, that would be my first suspect.

I have no knowledge one way or the other, but I could easily see Apple decide to disable that feature for ephemeral sessions, because it may or may not be trivial to avoid storing cookies, etc. when you are reusing connections and making multiple requests in parallel.

If that's the issue, you might see if there's some way to disable that feature either on the server end or the client end.  I don't know of a way to do so off the top of my head, though.

Comment: For the case of Simulator on macOs 12.4, The problem seems to be region specific. When the same test is performed from London region, there is no performance degradation. I am able to reproduce the issue in sample app (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/main/S3TransferUtility-Sample/Objective-C) and have filed the bug with Apple feedback assistant.

Comment: Any chance the request is being throttled by your ISP or by S3 because of some difference in the request headers/cookies?

Comment: I have checked the request headers and didn't find anything suspicious there.
Also, have performed the tests with different Networks as well, but the issue persists.
Not sure, but may be opening a ticket on S3 may give some clue as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the next logical step.  I'm assuming you aren't doing anything weird with NSURLProtocol or anything.  One big difference with QUIC is that it uses UDP, so if the server has QUIC enabled, you might be running into a problem caused by UDP getting deprioritized by the network.  Also possibly related: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714393

Comment: Issue got fixed by using responsiveData Network serviceType for the streamed requests.https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/networkservicetype/responsivedata

There was a bug in iOS 14 where background session was not using background  network algorithm (LEDBAT) but it was wrongly using foreground network algorithm. This bug was fixed in iOS 15 along with a lot of other optimizations for background network algorithm.
This could be the reason of upload working fine till iOS 14 but started giving performance issues from iOS 15 onwards.

Comment: It is still not clear, why the performance degradation was not being observed in US and EU regions.